# Shifting HR Tag

Tags: html

My HR tag begins too soon. I'd like to add 1-2 units of blank space before the HR displays.

Currently, it looks like:

```
----------------
```

But I'd like to change it to:

```
xx-------------- // where x means blank space
```

I would try the `align`, but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) says it's obsolete in HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CSS

```
hr {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Would `px` be preferred over `em` since, as I understand, the former is an absolute amount regardless of browser?

Comment: `px` and `em` have their own strengths and weaknesses.  Since you indicated you wanted two blank spaces, using `2em` seemed like the closest fit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<hr style="width:80%; float: right; clear: both" />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuXRT/)

Comment: Thank you, this worked and I plus'd up. But I chose Chris's answer since it was shorter.